# Whats the error in the C code?

Tags: c

I have a code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int i;
    i = 20;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(i));
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error like this:

```
In function `main':
undefined reference to `i'
```

Even though I have defined `i` why there is an error thrown?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared i to be defined in a separate file, but haven't linked to an external file.

If you remove the extern keyword, this will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

> The extern keyword declares a variable or function and specifies that
>   it has external linkage (its name is visible from files other than the
>   one in which it's defined). When modifying a variable, extern
>   specifies that the variable has static duration (it is allocated when
>   the program begins and deallocated when the program ends). The
>   variable or function may be defined in another source file, or later
>   in the same file. Declarations of variables and functions at file
>   scope are external by default.

Where is `i` defined?

Try this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  i = 20;
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(i));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or instead put a `int i;` after the `}` and leave the `extern int i`

Answer (score 0):

The "extern" keyword is you telling the compiler "This variable is define somewhere else, just use it and trust me that it will be available at linking time."